C++ Builder TOpenDialog - How to increase the limit on the number of selected files?
I am running into a problem where the number of files that can be opened in the dialog is limited to about 600. When selecting more than this number, the edit box at the bottom of the dialog becomes empty and no files are opened.
The files that need to be opened with the application come with relatively long names (70+ characters) and this is no doubt a factor, but that cannot be changed. The application needs to be able to open more than 5000 files.
The question is, where/how is the limit defined, and can it be increased? If so, how?
From what I could find, this is not a problem that anyone else has reported for C++Builder. I did find one post related to Delphi with the same issue, but the suggested resolution (increasing the global variable OpenDialogMaxMultiSelFiles) did not work with C++Builder because I could not find any reference to it anywhere.

Just out of curiosity, why in the world would you need to open that many files at once? Your app will run out of memory long before it can open them if they contain anything at all. It's impossible for a user to manage that many open files at once, not to mention that the user interface that would be needed wouldn't fit on even the most high-resolution screens.

It doesn't open them all at the same time but iterates through the TString list and opens and processes the files one at a time. The data from the processing of each file is then displayed in a TstringGrid.

Then why does the user need to select all of them at once? And why use an OpenDialog at all, instead of just iterating the files in a folder that match a file mask and putting them in a list? I find it doubtful that a user would want to Shift+Click or Ctrl+Click in an OpenFileDialog to select that many files.

All valid points, but I'd still like to know how to increase the number of files I can select with TOpenDialog.

TOpenFileDialog is a wrapper around the WinAPI function GetOpenFileNameW(), which accepts a structure OPENFILENAMEW (older non-Unicode Delphi uses the A versions of the functions and structure). That structure contains a DWORD member named nMaxFile, which defines the size in bytes of a buffer (lpstrFile) which will contain the path and list of selected files, with a NULL separator between them. You would have to enlarge both the nMaxFile value and the size of the lpstrFile buffer before calling that function. I'm not aware of any way to do so using TOpenFileDialog.

(continued) The documentation for GetOpenFileNameW for more information about the structure and its contents and the use of the function. (FWIW, I still think this is an XY problem, and that your UI is flawed, and if you fixed that issue you wouldn't have to worry about this at all.)

ok. Thank you. I think I will take your advice and use a list.

Took me less than five minutes. I don't why I wasted so much time trying to make it work.

I hate it when that happens. :-) Not when I find a solution that works, but when I realize how much time I wasted getting there.

Indeed :-). I think the lesson here is that if it doesn't work there must be a better way.

@Sheepy the reason you couldn't find OpenDialogMaxMultiSelFiles in C++Builder is because it doesn't exist. Not in Delphi, either. It is actually part of a 3rd party library called ImageEn, which has its own dialogs for opening image files. (Ref)

The legacy TOpenDialog VCL component is a wrapper for the Win32 GetOpenFileName() and IFileOpenDialog APIs. Which API it uses internally depends on various criteria.
If all of the following conditions are met, it will use IFileOpenDialog:

the Windows version is Vista or later.
the Vcl.Dialogs.UseLatestCommonDialogs global variable is True (which it is by default).
a custom VCL Style is not active, or the shDialogs flag is not enabled in TStyleManager.SystemHooks.
Win32 Visual Styles are enabled (ie, an app manifest enables Comctl32.dll v6, and IsAppThemed() returns true).
the Template property is nil
the OnIncludeItem, OnClose, and OnShow events do not have handlers assigned to them.

If any of those conditions are not met, TOpenDialog uses GetOpenFileName() instead.
When TOpenDialog uses GetOpenFileName(), it uses a fixed-sized character buffer to receive the selected filenames from the API.  When the ofAllowMultiSelect flag is enabled, the size of that buffer is 65519 characters max, and the API fills it with the full path to the parent directory followed by a list of the selected filenames within that directory.  That buffer can easily be exhausted with more than 600 files selected.  And there is no option for this buffer to be allocated dynamically based on how many files are selected, the buffer has to be provided up front when the API is called.  So, the only way to increase this limit (without modifying the VCL's source code) is to simply call GetOpenFileName() yourself giving it a larger buffer to work with, ie 1.5-2MB should suffice.
When TOpenDialog uses IFileOpenDialog, it receives a single IShellItemArray from the API, which provides an enumeration into an array of IShellItems, one for each selected file. And each full file path+name is retrieved dynamically from each IShellItem. As such, this approach should be limited only by available memory.
If you want to force the IFileOpenDialog behavior, you can use the TFileOpenDialog component instead.  Just know it won't work on pre-Vista versions of Windows, if you need that.
